# Preload script not loading in electron react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, preload

I'm building an app with React and Electron and trying to create a communication channel between the main (electron.js in my case) and renderer processes. By achieving this, I want to access the Store object created in my main process to save user preferences etc.

I have set up a preload script and provided the path in my main.js (electron.js). But when I try to access the method defined in the preload.js from the renderer like this `window.electronAPI.sendData('user-data', this.state)`, it does not recognise the electronAPI (undefined variable electronAPI). Also the console.log in my preload.js is never shown when a window is loaded. Hence I assume the preload script never gets loaded and I don't know why. Any help is very much appreciated!

**EDIT:** The preload script seems to load now because the console.log gets printed. Maybe preload.js did load before too but I could not see it since I could only access the application by opening localhost:3000 in the browser. Now the app opens in a BrowserWindow. However the 'electronAPI' defined in the preload script cannot be accessed still.

Here is the code:

electron.js (main.js)

```
const electron = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu, ipcMain} = electron;

let isDev = process.env.APP_DEV ? (process.env.APP_DEV.trim() === "true") : false;

function createWindow (){
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 970,
        height: 600,
        backgroundColor: '#0C0456',
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: true,
            enableRemoteModule: false,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

   //if in development mode, load window from localhost:3000 otherwise build from index.html
    try {
        win.webContents.loadURL(isDev
            ? 'http://localhost:3000'
            : `file://${path.join(__dirname,'../build/index.html')}`
        )
    } catch(e){
        console.error(e)
    }


    win.webContents.openDevTools({"mode":"detach"});

    //Remove menu
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(null);

    win.once('ready-to-show', () => win.show());
    console.log("main window is shown");
    console.log(typeof path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'));


    win.on('crashed',() => {
        console.error(`The renderer process has crashed.`);
    })


}


app.on( 'ready', () => {
    createWindow(); // open default window
} );

ipcMain.on('user-data', (event, args)=>{
    console.log(args);
});
```

preload.js

```
const {contextBridge, ipcRenderer} = require("electron");

const validChannels  = ['user-data'];

console.log("this is the preload script");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
    sendData: (channel, data) => {
        if(validChannels.includes(channel)){
            ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Let's eliminate any obvious issues first. Is your `preload.js` script in the same directory as your `main.js` script?

Comment: @midnight-coding yes, both are in the same directory.

Comment: Please see the edit above.

Comment: Good news your `preload.js` script is loading now. Now, what do you mean by "the 'electronAPI' defined in the preload script cannot be accessed"? Do you have any render process console errors? Additionally, you should add to your question the main process code where you receive the `user-data` message. IE: Something like `ipcMain.on('user-data', (event, data) => { console.log(data); });`

Comment: "electronAPI" is the API key defined in the `contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld()` method (see preload.js code above). When I try to access the corresponding method `sendData()` (defined inside exposeInMainWorld()) from a renderer component using this line of code: window.electronAPI.sendData(), Intellij underlines the electronAPI part and when I hover over it, it says "Unresolved variable electronAPI". But now that I tried again, despite that it seems to work and the main.js receives the data and prints it.  So I guess, problem solved! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear it is working for you. Yes, the JetBrains products (IntelliJ, PhpStorm, etc) places a squiggly line underneath this part of your code as static code analysis can't resolve it. Using a `namespace` declaration in a Docblock will clear the unresolved variable. EG: `/** @namespace window.electronAPI */`. Else, you may be able to use some type of stub file, though I have no experience with this…